# Практика по CSS. Что не так с кодом?

Tags: css

Задача стоит сделать так же, как в примере. Сделала аналогично, но показывает сходство только на 22%)) Что не так сделала? Спасибо заранее.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
 <head>        
   <title>codebra</title>    
 </head>    
 <body>        
   <p class="big">Joy of <span class="tex">T<span>E</span>X</span></p>    
 </body>
</html>



.big {
    font-size: 48px;

}
.tex {
   letter-spacing: -4.8px;

}
.tex span {
   vertical-align:-9px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Щас налетят в комменты) Скиньте задание и свой код, чтобы можно было посмотреть)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: Sans;
 font-size: 45px;
}

.element {
 vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>TEX</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
Joy of T<span class="element">E</span>X
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло.

Comment: подправил, попробуйте так

Comment: Теперь на 30% сходство, но визуально сходства значительно меньше)

Comment: снова редактировал код, через вертикальное выравнивание не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовала, получилось сделать аналогично примеру, не меняя ничего в HTML-коде, только добавив в CSS letter-spacing, font-size и vertical-align. Не понимаю, почему не принимает мой вариант, если поставленная задача выполнена.